# Is Flash Player natively installed on Android 2.2?

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to use flash player in one of my applications and I was wondering if Android 2.2 phones come with Flash Player installed or do I have to manually install it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use Flash player. Use some android animation API, much faster.
2. Android devices do not come with Flash. Only if you have a Snapdragon-like processor (ARMv7+) will you be able to install it. So older phones are out of luck. HTC does have a limited "HTC Flash player", but it only works well on youtube and similar sites. It has problems anywhere else.